# keysSortedByValueUsingSelector crashes but sortedArrayUsingSelector runs fine

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, nsmutabledictionary

I found a workaround myself, but still trying to understand the problem.

I created a Autocomplete text field with the use of uitableview which is hidden until textfield is edited. The UI part works fine. It's the searching for the results part that's the problem. I declared a local NSMutableDictionary to store my results because I wanted the results to be sorted by the key's values.

if I call keysSortedByValueUsingSelector on the dictionary directly, it crashes. However if I get the keys by [dict allKeys] first, then call sortedArrayUsingSelector, it works fine:

```
// This commented out line will crash
//    NSArray *sortedKeysArray = [dict keysSortedByValueUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

    // The next two lines runs fine.
        NSArray *keyArray = [dict allKeys];
        NSArray *sortedKeysArray = [keyArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

Here is the complete source code for the search method:

```
- (void)searchAutocompleteEntriesWithSubstring:(NSString *)substring
{
    // Put anything that starts with this substring into the autocompleteUrls array
    // The items in this array is what will show up in the table view
    [autocomplete_symbol_array removeAllObjects];
    rRSIAppDelegate *appDelegate = (rRSIAppDelegate *)([[UIApplication sharedApplication]    delegate]);
    NSString *input_str = [substring uppercaseString];

NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    int i = 0;
    for(SymbolInfo *symbol_info in appDelegate.m_symbol_info_array)
    {
        i++;
        NSString *info_str = [[[symbol_info.m_symbol uppercaseString] stringByAppendingString:@"|"] stringByAppendingString:[symbol_info.m_company_name uppercaseString]];
        NSUInteger pos = [info_str rangeOfString:input_str].location;
        if (pos != NSNotFound)
        {
            int tmp = pos * 10000 + i;
            NSNumber *map_key = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:tmp];
            [dict setObject:symbol_info forKey:map_key];
        }
    }

// This commented out line will crash
//    NSArray *sortedKeysArray = [dict keysSortedByValueUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

// The next two lines runs fine.
    NSArray *keyArray = [dict allKeys];
    NSArray *sortedKeysArray = [keyArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

    for (NSNumber *key in sortedKeysArray)
    {
        SymbolInfo *symbol_info = [dict objectForKey:key];
        [autocomplete_symbol_array addObject:symbol_info];
    }

//    NSLog(@"everything added: %d", [autocomplete_symbol_array count]);
    [autocompleteTableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: The two examples you have given are not equivalent. When using `keysSortedByValueUsingSelector:`, the values are being compared, and when using `allKeys` + `sortedArrayUsingSelector:`, only the keys are compared. You could add the crash logs to the code below. I think your dictionary objects as values that either don't implement the `compare:` method, or you are trying to compare objects of different types and one of them is throwing an exception.

Comment: I could not have been that stupid!! I thought keysSortedByValueUsingSelector() sorts the keys by their values! Examples from this link clearly demonstrates it:  http://mobiledevelopertips.com/data-file-management/sort-a-dictionary-using-the-value-in-key-value-pair.html

Answer (score 0):

The NSMutableDictionary's method is:

```
- (void)setObject:(id)anObject forKey:(id < NSCopying >)aKey;
```

This means that the key should implement the [NSCopying protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCopying_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).